# $.when not working for me

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have followed all the advice I found here at [Wait until all jQuery Ajax requests are done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-request-are-done) but I must be missing something basic.

I have this function...

```
function ListScores(leaguex, nameid) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'sg_ajaxListData.php',
        data: {
            nme: nameid,
            league: leaguex
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (rows) {
            for (var i in rows) {
                var row = rows[i];
                var score1 = row["score1"];
                var score2 = row["score2"];
                var round = row["round"];
                $('#output').append("<br />Round " + round + " - " + score1);
                if (leaguex == 'r') {
                    $('#output').append(" " + score2);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It is called from the document.ready function of my code and works perfectly, returning the data and displaying it as expected.
I want another function to run AFTER ListScores() has displayed its data so, elsewhere in the document.ready function I put...

```
$.when(ListScores()).done(function(a1){
console.log("hello",leaguex,nameid, a1);
});
```

... but nothing ever shows up in the console log so it looks like this function is never being called.
Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: By passing `ListScores()` you're trying to call the function

Comment: You don't really need the `.when` there, you could just do `ListScores().done(function() {...})`, but it should work as is.. check your console, and you might try adding `.fail()` and `.always()` callbacks to see if either of those trigger.

Comment: @hjpotter92 But `ListScores()` returns a promise, so it should work.

Comment: Can you show all of the code? One thing I noticed is that you don't pass any parameters to your LightScores function in $.when. Do you see request go through successfully?

Comment: Agreed with Jason P, you don't really need $.when in this case.

Comment: @MyP3uK Completely missed that, I bet that's the problem. @sclg, are you calling `ListScores()` twice? Because you should only call it once.

Comment: Do I need parameters in ListScores in the .when line? I assumed that line was just saying 'wait for the ListScores function to return after it is called somewhere else'??

Comment: @sclg Not as you have it written. You could wrap `ListScores` with another function and create a module that caches the response if you want to call it more than once.

Comment: Nope, ListScores() invokes the function immediately and passes its return value, a Promise object in this case, to $.when().

Comment: Thanks both - You are both right of course - I had misunderstood the syntax. Now doing what I want.

Answer (score -1):

Edit :
after@ Jason P comment, I think this wrong solution 
But I will keep it as it shows how to autoinvoke a function 
---End of edit

It is not firing because ListScores() was never invoked

You should wrap the ListScores() and immediately invoked it.

```
function ListScores(){

}
```

To invoke it

You should add the following

```
 (function ListScores(){

 })();
```

Got it?

Comment: The expression `ListScores()` doesn't invoke the `ListScores` function?

Comment: Yep - misunderstanding now sorted!